# How can I remove the vertical spacing between UITableView sections?

Tags: uitableview

I have a grouped table view with a few sections. By default, there is gap between the sections. I've been looking around for a simple way to remove the gap completely without any luck. The best I could do through the Interface Builder is to set the "Section Height" values in the "Table View Size" property section, but these fields do not accept 0 as valid input. Can anyone tell me the best way to sort this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your table view's delegate, you can implement [`tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aheightForHeaderInSection%3a) and [`tableView:heightForFooterInSection:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aviewForFooterInSection%3a).

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 0.0;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 0.0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The above answer for me did not work, I had to actually create a UIView with a height of 1 and a background color of clear and then set it's y origin coordinate to -1.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -1, tableView.frame.size.width, 1)];
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    return view;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}
```

This gave me a Grouped tableView where the section cells would not scroll underneath the headerView and not have padding in-between the sections.